# Send messages through Voice Recognition?

Tags: android, android-intent

I used the following code to send a message "hello" when I say send.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);   
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getClass().getPackage().getName());
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, metTextHint.getText().toString());  
startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);
```

In `onActivityResult()` :

```
if(textMatchList.get(0).contains("send")) {    
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Hello"); 
smsIntent.putExtra("address", "0123456789");  
smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");  
startActivity(smsIntent);  
}
```

How can I make the app be more flexible. I mean for example if I say "Send this message to mike, Hey man, you want to go to the movie." How can I make the app use only the important information like Send, Mike, and the message itself. And then send the message as usual. Also how make this all possible without hard-coding it.

Are there any tutorials which do this on the net, if so please give me a link, I would really appreciate that.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you might get the text of the recognized speech and use

```
if(text.contains("Mike")){
//send message to Mike (which i dont know how to do it,i am searching for this )
}
```